# Log Shipping back up location to a network share instead of clustered file share

Tags: sql-server, clustering, log-shipping, backup, netbackup

Below is my current cluster set up

- Node 1 - Active
- Node 2 - Passive

While doing Log SHipping can I save the back ups to a network share instead of a clustered file share?

The service account will have read/write permission on the network share.

Comment: I will disable the log back ups that are part of the maintenance plan but the log back up job for log shipping will keep running in order to avoid breaking the lsn

Answer (score 2):

Log shipping backups aren't anything special under the hood, they run an executable (sqllogship.exe) that fires off a standard `BACKUP LOG`. They can be configured to point anywhere the service account has write access to (and since this is a FCI, anywhere that is reachable from both nodes).

What's the point of writing these to a network share? Reduce the shared storage requirements (presuming there's no direct attached storage you can easily use)?